# Vertically align responsive width and height image

Tags: css

I have a div that will change width with the size of the screen. I also want the height of the div to resize with the image up to a maximum height and then any of the overflowing image will be hidden.

So far I have only been able to center the image using absolute positioning, but this means that I also have to include a placeholder image of the same size so that the div will change height:

```css
#test {
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#test .test-image {
  width: 100%;
}
#test .vertical-align {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <!-- this is a placeholder to make the div height expand / contract depending on the width -->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1" class="test-image">
  
  <!-- this is the vertically aligned image -->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1" class="test-image vertical-align">
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this using relative positioning so I do not need to include the placeholder image?

I thought of the following but it does not seem to work as it just seems to move the image back to where it started and crop from the bottom rather than centering:

```css
#test {
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#test .test-image {
  width: 100%;
}
#test .vertical-align {
  margin-top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <!-- this is the vertically aligned image -->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1" class="test-image vertical-align"> 
</div>
```

Is this possible with pure css?  Please only post css solutions - no js answers.

Thanks

**Update**

I've managed to figure out why the absolute works but the relative doesn't - when absolute, the `top:50%` is 50% of the parent div, whereas when relative, the `margin-top:50%` is 50% of the image height, which is why the translate just moves it back to it's starting place.

So I guess any solution will be based on moving the image down 50% of the parents height before applying the transform.  I've played with padding on the parent but that doesn't seem to work at either

Comment: You could always change the `min-height` to something like `50vh`. It does have some problems though (especially on older iOS devices) http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units. I am very interested to see if someone can come up with a different CSS based work-around though.

Comment: @Frits Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the vertically centering image problem

Comment: Blame my lack of caffeine, but I am struggling to understand your edit - could you have a look at this and replicate your problem on it for me? https://jsfiddle.net/oq8fosbd/2/, otherwise, if I did understand your problem correctly, you can substitute the `margin-top:50%;` for a `top:50%;`

Comment: @Frits I tried with just top but doesn't seem to work on a relative positioned element: https://jsfiddle.net/b4ug8xog/2/ (left is relative, right is absolute)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can set the image to have an absolute position?

Comment: @Frits, due to the extra image you need - didn't really want to have 2 images for every image I wanted to be responsive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution with flex, I hope you find it useful:

```css
#test {
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#test .test-image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1" class="test-image">
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I've only made it work in IE 11 by adding an extra div. Maybe it's not enough for you but I spent all my resources.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#test {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  align-content:center;
  display: flex;
}

#test .test-image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="test">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1" class="test-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done! I think this is much neater than messing around with positions and translates.

Comment: Damn, just noticed this doesn't work in sh**ty IE(11), do you have an IE flex workaround?

Comment: Oh, it is true, it doesn't work in IE11. I've tried a few things but I couldn't fix it.